# Finding $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k+3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I Already proved that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+2} = 1
$$

But I fail to formally prove that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k+3} = \infty
$$
I can understand by intuition that it does, but can't manage to find an $N$ so that every $n > N$
makes $a_n > M$.

Comment: For $k>3:$ $1/2=\frac{k}{k+k}<\frac{k}{k+3}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Aviram. Can you follow my answer?if not say so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k>3$; $(1/2)=\frac{k}{k+k}<\frac{k}{k+3};$

$\sum_{4}^{n}(1/2)<\sum_{4}^{n}\frac{k}{k+3}$;

$(1/2)(n-4) \rightarrow \infty$.

Hence?

Comment: Thanks!
That helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k+3}=n+\frac{11}{2}-3 H_{n+3}$$
$$S_n=\frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k+3}=\frac{n}{n+2}\left(n+\frac{11}{2}-3 H_{n+3} \right)$$ Using asymptotics and continuing with Taylor expansions
$$S_n=n-\left(3 \log (n)+3 \gamma -\frac{7}{2}\right)+\frac{6 \log (n)+6 \gamma
   -\frac{35}{2}}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Use it for $n=10$; the exact result is
$$S_{10}=\frac{715867}{144144} \approx 4.966$$ while the above truncated expansion gives
$$\frac{235-48 \gamma -48 \log (10)}{20} \approx 4.838$$

Answer (score 0):

How about $N=3$ and $M=\frac12$?

Comment: $M$ should a general number, so that for every $M$ there is an index $N$, so that every $n > N$ gives us $a_n > M$

Comment: But since $a_4,a_5,\ldots$ are all greater than $1/2$, the series diverges.

Comment: So it doesn't converge to infinity? I don't fully understand. The deltas between each member converge to 1, so intuitively I thought that the $\displaystyle a_n \to_{n \to \infty} \infty $.

Comment: It diverges to $\infty$. By $a_n$, I assumed you meant the terms in the series. Do you mean the partial sums? The limit of the partial sums does not exist (or if you like, $=\infty$), so the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The individual terms $k/(k+3)\to1\ne0$.  So the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Since $k \mapsto \frac{k}{k+3}$ is increasing and $k \geq 1$ it is $\frac{k}{k+3} \geq \frac{1}{4}$; so
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+3} \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{4} \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^n 1=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{4} \frac{n^2}{n+2}$$

It is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{4} \frac{n^2}{n+2} =\infty$$
Then by comparison it is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+3}=\infty$$